# How to delete multiple columns at the same time with find column index funciton

Tags: vba, excel

I have done a bit of googling and can not figure out how to delete multiple columns at the same time.  Being that the data that will be inputted into this tool will not be consistent I have to use a find function to denote which column to delete. Right now, only the first delete function works and the rest are ignored.  I have used messageboxes to insure the find functions are properly pulling the correct column index.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to delete multiple?  Thanks!

```
Vertical = Worksheets("Target List").Rows("1").Find("Vertical").Column
DistID = Worksheets("Target List").Rows("1").Find("Distributor ID").Column
DistName = Worksheets("Target List").Rows("1").Find("Distributor Name").Column

Sheets("Target List").Select
Columns(Vertical).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(DistID).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(DistName).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
dim i as long, col as variant, c as variant

col = array("Vertical", "Distributor ID", "Distributor Name")

with Worksheets("Target List")
    for i=lbound(col) to ubound(col)
        c= application.match(col(i), .rows(1), 0)
        if not iserror(c) then .columns(c).entirecolumn.delete
    next i
end with
```

Attempting to delete the columns all at once will demand reiterative error control. Better to simply delete them one at a time.

Comment: Nothing happened :/

Comment: When you step through with F8, what is the value of *c* in the Locals window?

Comment: I'm dumb! It worked. I was looking at the wrong worksheet.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach I personally find easier to understand:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet 
Dim Lastcolumn As Long 
Dim y As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Lastcolumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For y = Lastcolumn To 1 Step -1
    If sht.Cells(1, y) = "Vertical" Or sht.Cells(1, y) = "Distributor ID" Or sht.Cells(1, y) = "Distributor Name" Then
        sht.Columns(y).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If 
Next
```

Instead of exact comparison you could use also Instr() for when you don't know exactly the header string.

Hope it helps.